# Greasemonkey script not working against dynamically inserted widget

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a Greasemonkey script that will automatically give focus to the captcha input field if found. This works fine except in the case when the captcha form is inserted dynamically, like [this example](http://www.solvemedia.com/publishers/captcha-type-in). I thought creating an event listener for DOMNodeInserted is supposed to handle that case. (I'm testing on Firefox 17b).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Focus captcha field
// @description   Adds focus on captcha fields
// ==/UserScript==

function focusCaptcha (elem) {
    var ids = ['recaptcha_response_field', 'adcopy_response', 'captcha_input'];
    for (var i = ids.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var input = elem.getElementById(ids[i]);
        if (input) {
            input.focus();
            input.value = '';
            return;
        }
    }
}

(function() {
    focusCaptcha(document);
})();

document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
    focusCaptcha(event.target);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

`DOMNodeInserted` is a *Mutation Event* and [**Mutation Events are deprecated**](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents) for a good reason.  That code could seriously load the browser's JS and possibly trigger some of the "Script busy / out-of-control" safeguards.

You could switch to the brand new [MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver), but that is complicated overkill for this sort of thing.

Use the tried and true [waitForKeyElements() utility](https://gist.github.com/2625891).  Like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Focus captcha field
// @description Adds focus on captcha fields
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change introduced
    in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

function focusCaptcha (jNode) {
    jNode.val ('');
    jNode[0].focus ();
}

waitForKeyElements (
    "#recaptcha_response_field, #adcopy_response, #captcha_input#",
    focusCaptcha
);
```

---

Beware that iframes *might* complicate things when trying to move focus (haven't tested that though).

Comment: Afert looking at MutationObservers it was simple and not much code. And no offense, but I'm wary of relying on a gist script.

Comment: The gist script code is fully visible, and not complicated -- it's easy to see that it's risk free.  If you're worried that it could change, paste the source into your script or create your own free fork -- which you control.